# gallery post filter with pagination not working

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress, pagination

I have create post gallery and I have used 4 type of taxonomy also I want to filter all posts with pagination but my filter is not working properly. when I have select model -> ford then posts is not display in 1st page there is display in 2nd page.

```
<div class="gallery-section">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="fillter-head">
                    <div class="row">
                        <?php
                        $taxonomy = 'type_cat';
                        $tax_terms = get_terms($taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                        ?>
                        <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="filters" id="filters">
                                <?php
                                $count = count($tax_terms);
                                if ($count > 0) {
                                    ?>
                                    <?php
                                    foreach ($tax_terms as $term_single) {
                                        $termname = $term_single->slug;
                                        ?>
                                        <li><a href="#" data-rel="<?php echo $termname; ?>" data-filter=".<?php echo $termname; ?>" class="fil-type"><?php echo $term_single->name; ?></a></li>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="gallery-menu">
                                <ul>
                                    <?php
                                    $make_taxonomy = 'make_cat';
                                    $tax_makes = get_terms($make_taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                                    ?>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="javascript:void(0)">MAKE</a>
                                        <ul class="gallery-submenu" id="filters">
                                            <?php
                                            $count1 = count($tax_makes);
                                            if ($count1 > 0) {
                                                foreach ($tax_makes as $tax_make) {
                                                    $termname_make = $tax_make->slug;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <li><a href="#" data-rel="<?php echo $termname_make; ?>" data-filter=".<?php echo $termname_make; ?>"><?php echo $tax_make->name; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <?php
                                    $model_taxonomy = 'model_cat';
                                    $tax_models = get_terms($model_taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">MODEL</a>
                                        <ul class="gallery-submenu" id="filters">
                                            <?php
                                            $count_model = count($tax_models);
                                            if ($count_model > 0) {
                                                foreach ($tax_models as $tax_model) {
                                                    $termname_model = $tax_model->slug;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <li><a href="#" data-rel="<?php echo $termname_model; ?>" data-filter=".<?php echo $termname_model; ?>"><?php echo $tax_model->name; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                    <?php
                                    $wheel_model_taxonomy = 'wheel_model_cat';
                                    $tax_wheel_models = get_terms($wheel_model_taxonomy, array('hide_empty' => false));
                                    ?>
                                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">WHEEL MODEL</a>
                                        <ul class="gallery-submenu" id="filters">
                                            <?php
                                            $count_wheel_model = count($tax_wheel_models);
                                            if ($count_wheel_model > 0) {
                                                foreach ($tax_wheel_models as $tax_wheel_model) {
                                                    $termname_wheel_model = $tax_wheel_model->slug;
                                                    ?>
                                                    <li><a href="#" data-rel="<?php echo $termname_wheel_model; ?>" data-filter=".<?php echo $termname_wheel_model; ?>"><?php echo $tax_wheel_model->name; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                            <?php } ?>
                                        </ul>
                                    </li>

                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <?php
                // Get a list of categories
                $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? absint(get_query_var('paged')) : 1;
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'post_gallery',
                    'posts_per_page' => 9,
                    'order_by' => 'date',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
//                    'paged' => $paged,
                );

                $new_query = new WP_Query($args);
        //             print_r($new_query);
                ?>
                <div id="gallery" class="gallery">
                    <?php
                    if ($new_query->have_posts()) :
                        while ($new_query->have_posts()) : $new_query->the_post();
                            $terms = get_the_terms($new_query->ID, 'type_cat');
                            $terms_makes = get_the_terms($new_query->ID, 'make_cat');
                            $terms_models = get_the_terms($new_query->ID, 'model_cat');
                            $terms_wheel_models = get_the_terms($new_query->ID, 'wheel_model_cat');

                            $gallery_videos = get_field('gallery_videos');
                            $gallery_poster_images = get_field('gallery_poster_images');
                            ?>
                            <!-- gallery item -->
                            <div class="item columns4 scale-anm <?php
                            if ($terms || $terms_makes || $terms_models || $terms_wheel_models):
                                foreach ($terms as $term) {
                                    echo $term->slug;
                                }
                                foreach ($terms_makes as $terms_make) {
                                    echo ' ' . $terms_make->slug;
                                }
                                foreach ($terms_models as $terms_model) {
                                    echo ' ' . $terms_model->slug;
                                }
                                foreach ($terms_wheel_models as $terms_wheel_model) {
                                    echo ' ' . $terms_wheel_model->slug;
                                }
                            endif;
                            ?>">
                                     <?php if ($gallery_videos): ?>
                                    <div class="item-wrap">
                                        <img src="<?php echo $gallery_poster_images; ?>" data-video="<?php echo $gallery_videos; ?>" class="videoPoster">
                                    </div>
                                <?php else: ?>

                                    <div class="item-wrap">
                                        <a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>">
                                            <?php the_post_thumbnail('gallery-page-img'); ?>
                                        </a>
                                        <div class="image_links hover-title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink(get_the_ID()); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></div>
                                        <!--<div class="image_links hover-title"><a href="#">2016 Dodge Charger Hellcat ‘Plum Loca’ – FR5 Matte Graphite</a></div>-->
                                    </div>

                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                            <?php
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_postdata();
                        ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!-- close gallery item -->

                </div>
<!--                <div class="gallery-pagination">
                    <ul class="pagination">-->
                <?php if (function_exists("pagination")) { ?>
                    <?php pagination($new_query->max_num_pages); ?>
                <?php } ?>
<!--                    </ul>
                </div>-->
            </div>
        </div>
```

This is my PHP code and that is working fine but my filter is not working properly.

Please any suggestion for that.

Also, I'm using ajax through pagination but i don't know its not working.

Please any-one help me about that.